# How to change state through react-router-dom Link?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-link

I am trying to change the state through a Link component when I click on an image. I'm not sure if it's how the Link component is written or if the `clickHandler` is incorrectly used, but it console logs the state as true even after I click it.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import {Link, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import RecipePage from './RecipePage'
export default function Recipes({dataArray}){

const [strMeal, setStrMeal] = useState(true)

function clickHandler(){
    setStrMeal(false)
}




return(
    <div>
        <Link to={{pathname:'/recipepage', state: {strMeal: strMeal} }}>
            <div onClick={() => clickHandler()}>This is an image</div>
        </Link>
    </div>
    
)
```

}

How do I change the state to false?

Comment: react not store the state value until you are using [`useContext`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) or `redux`. Each time of the navigation that state value reset to default like your `useState(true)`

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended to use onClick handler on `<Link />` component itself:

`<Link to={{pathname:'/recipepage', state: {strMeal: strMeal} }} onClick={(e) => clickHandler(e)}`>

Now, you'll also need to prevent the default behavior of the link:

```
function clickHandler(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    setStrMeal(false)
}
```

---

But I am not sure why you want to do this? Since, Link is used to go to the path you provide. So, I guess you want to do something on `/recipepage`:

So, you'll get the pathname, or even with the state you've provided and do something with that there in the component.

Comment: I am trying to open up a page that displays the recipe info depending on which image I click. I have the fetch API ready to go. I would like to send the name of the recipe to the Link component so I could try to get the page to display the info.

Comment: And thank you, but I'm still having the initial issue!

Comment: Do necessary in that component with the props.